# ASP.NET Scaffolding/Templating CRUD Solutions

Tags: asp.net, templates, dynamic-data

I've been looking into ASP.NET Dynamic Data and how it does scaffolding and routing. I've only scratched the surface, but it's looking like I'd have to create a template for each table that I didn't want to display all columns the same way.

My first impression after looking at dynamic data is that it would seem like less time on the programmer to have to edit one-time generated user controls rather than build a template for each table that doesn't have a uniform display behavior.

**What proven solutions are people currently using that help ease the laborious tasks of creating ASP.NET CRUD type user controls?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously not much widespread use out there other than whats provided in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET webforms we use [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/). From a single entity we generate admin pages, codebehinds, service layers, data layers and db stored procedures. All in a matter of seconds. I'd recommend you check it our for quickly building the crud in your apps.

Comment: I've used CodeSmith before for generating sql server auditing triggers. Are you customizing a public set of scripts or wrote in house ones?

Comment: I've wrote our own inhouse ones Chad. The amount of work it has saved us is well into the many thousands of man hours. I used to be a classic ASP developer so writing the spagetti code style that CodeSmith uses is second nature to me (the pain of it that is) :)

Answer (score 2):

We're actually working on our own code generation tool. It has already proven to work perfectly on the lower layers and now we're on the way to extend it for the presentation layer, that is for generating user controls.

I've not looked into dynamic data (although I'd like to when I have some time) but my biggest fear is always to lose flexibility. The problem is that these front-ends are then maybe generated dynamically each time based on some template and editing, especially bringing in special customer wishes becomes quite difficult. For small standard apps it may work perfectly though.

What we're therefore doing is to "generate" these usercontrols based on a set of standard custom server controls we've developed, but we'll generate just the first time from some static information about the entities in our application. Then you can continue customizing.

Such systems should help the developer, improving his development speed, doing the initial awkward work but then they should give him the flexibility to modify till the maximum. They should not add additional complexity...

Answer (score 2):

I used [.netTiers](http://nettiers.com/) CodeSmith templates long time ago (years) and it was proven so strong, so, it must be more than great now.

I know a (big) company who have built a customization engine (allowing GUI for internal company options) around those templates to use them in most of their applications and were so successful.

Comment: I think this is what qualifies as "proven" solution, otherwise, I'd tell you to check ASP.NET Dynamic Data, which is still too young to go I think.

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://www.ironspeed.com/ in the past which has been great. Saved us MONTHS of time on our last project which has a big DB, so the cost is worth it. But it looks a bit ugly and can be tricky to update the DB schema once you've generated.

Comment: yea, that was my feeling with ironspeed as well. Difficult to customize the solution and still user their tool to update other items in the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Blinq](http://www.asp.net/downloads/sandbox/blinq/).