# Generate ASP.NET UserControl from Database

Tags: asp.net, scaffolding

Is there any existing software for generating a UserControl from a table of a database?

For example, my table contain 3 fields : name , last name , age.

The software generates a user control that has 3 labels and textboxes with validation and submit button and a gridview for displaying information , etc...

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into [Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata). It's an ASP.NET framework developed by Microsoft that automatically generates common UI elements based on Linq to SQL or Entity Framework objects (which are trivially easy to generate from a simple table like the one you mention.)

Comment: Hi my friend.
thanks for your attention.
does dynamic dynamic data better that asp.net maker?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't used ASP.NET Maker. I will say that Dynamic Data is well regarded, and being a Microsoft framework, plays nice with other approaches if you decide to add more customization or functionality to your site.

Comment: @this. __curious_gee Please describe more. what do you mean?

Comment: @shashin: sry. its a typo. Dynamic Data. Dynamic data best suits to ur need.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds an awful lot like UI "scaffolding". Take a look at the following article and related question:

[ASP.NET Scaffolding/Templating CRUD Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438976/asp-net-scaffolding-templating-crud-solutions)
[Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata)

Comment: thank you :)
does Dynamic data powerful tool?
dynamic data vs asp.net maker?

Comment: Dynamic data is fairly useful but it also has some limitations. You should try it out and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more O/R mapper capable of scaffolding (generating UI from database):
http://www.subsonicproject.com/